# How to avoid calling long operations from constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I use MVVM and I have to create a ViewModel class that should load lots of data when the View is opened.

Basically, when I create the viewmodel, it should use the database and get the data.

I used this approach first:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
 public MainViewModel()
 {
   //set some properties
   Title = "Main view";
   //collect the data
   StartLongOperation();
 }

 private void StartLongOperation()
 {
   Thread t=new Thread(...);
   t.start();
 }
}
```

It works and loads the data without blocking the UI thread.

Later I found [this guideline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about how to use constructor, and it does not recommend starting long operation from constructor.

> √ DO minimal work in the constructor.
>
> Constructors should not do much work other than capture the
> constructor parameters. The cost of any other processing should be
> delayed until required.

In my case, the data is required on opening the view.

My first idea was to use an *event*.

How should I avoid calling the long operation from construcTor? What is the best practice?

Comment: You're not really doing all that much in the constructor other than kicking off a thread. You might choose to move this into another method (`Init` or similar) to stick to the guidelines... However... this looks a bit racy to me. How can you be sure that the asynchronous work done in the thread is finished before you hand it to the view? Do you synchronize somewhere?

Comment: The thread gets the data and puts it into a list which is bound to a grid.

Comment: You're not doing the work in the constructor.  There is no issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Miguel Castro has talked about a solution to this in one of his great Pluralsight courses.  He binds to a property in the viewmodel called ViewLoaded which will obviously get bound when the view loads, this in turn will call your long running method.

So this goes in the view (Or a base class for all views to help with re-use):

```
    public ViewBase()
    {
        // Programmatically bind the view-model's ViewLoaded property to the view's ViewLoaded property.
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ViewLoadedProperty, new Binding("ViewLoaded"));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewLoadedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ViewLoaded", typeof(object), typeof(UserControlViewBase),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

And this is the ViewModel base class code:

```
public object ViewLoaded
{
    get
    {
        OnViewLoaded();
        return null;
    }
}

protected virtual void OnViewLoaded() { }
```

Simply override the OnViewLoaded() method in your ViewModel and call the long running method from there.

Comment: Interesting approach, I like this, too.

Comment: Thanks, but as noted above, it was Miguels idea not mine.  I like it because it means no calling of public viewmodel methods from the view and it won't run until the view loads.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a factory pattern to avoid having the MainViewModel around but not populated.

```
    public class VMFactory
    {
        public async Task<MainViewModel> GetVM()
        {
            MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel();
            await vm.LongOperation();
            return vm;
        }
    }

    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            //set some properties
            Title = "Main view";
        }

        public async Task LongOperation()
        {
            (...)
        }
    }
```

or perhapse better. move the long running method out of the MainViewModel to a repository or service

```
    public class VMRepository
    {
        public async Task LongOperation()
        {
            (...)
        }

        public async Task<MainViewModel> GetVM()
        {
            MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel();
            vm.DataWhichTakesAlongTime  = await LongOperation();
            return vm;
        }
    }

    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            //set some properties
            Title = "Main view";
        }

        public object DataWhichTakesAlongTime { get; set; }
    }
```

To be honest though it sounds from the conversations around this question that you are simply using the constructor as a convenient trigger for a 'LoadDataNow' command and really you should add an ICommand, bind it to something in the view (Loaded) add loading spinners and completed events etc etc

Controversially I might also suggest you add a Controller Class to instantiate the repository view and vm and call the 'LoadData' method on the view. Not very MVVM I know but essentially doing the same stuff your IoC container does without having to jump through the hoops of configuration

Comment: Yes, it is sort of that thing. Using events or bindings is also a good solution, I was considering using them.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding calling it is simple, just split it into 2 methods; The constructor and a GetData method you call when you open the view or after you set the data context.

The why is just about managing expectation. If you hadn't written the code and were writing a new view for someone else's view model, would you expect the constructor to start accessing a database? or would you expect it just to construct a view model and you need to make a second call to initiate getting the data?

Comment: If I _expect_ the constructor to start accessing the database, it is a violation of the MS guideline, I guess. The main question is if I create a second method, where should I call it: in OnDataContextChanged? Or any other event?

Comment: @Nestor Depends how you set up your view. You already need to call the constructor and set the datacontext. so you can call it as a public method in the same area.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know maybe it's wrong but sometimes i make(if i need retrun parameters)

```
public class MainViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            //set some properties
            Title = "Main view";
        }
        public static string GetMainViewModelString()
        {
            var mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            return mainViewModel.GetString();
        }
        public string GetString()
        {
            /*your code*/
        }
    }
```

and then call

```
var stringData = MainViewModel.GetMainViewModelString();
```

but when it need i call some operation from constructor

Comment: Is this based on a design pattern or only common sense?

Answer (score 0):

Use your view lifecycle to execute this method. You can use Tasks to simplify the execution and you can bind to other properties to show progress. Example shown using a Windows Store App view.

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Title = "Main view";
    }

    public async Task StartLongOperationAsync()
    {
        this.IsLoading = true;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //do work here
        });

        this.IsLoading = false;
    }
}
```

And on the View:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    await ((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).StartLongOperationAsync();
}
```

Comment: I'm interested in your use of await Task.Run. is this just to avoid the long hand writing out of the long running method?

Comment: @Ewan, Internally it wraps up threads and a threadpool and returns execution to the calling method when done. This book does a great job explaining the evolution from handwriting threads to using tasks: http://www.amazon.com/Exam-Ref-70-483-Programming-MCSD/dp/0735676828/ I'm currently studying for certification and the first chapter in this book cleared up a lot of task mysteries for me. Hopefully this answered your question, if not, leave another comment.

Comment: What I meant was, why not have protected async DoStuff() {//do work here} and await that. im using Task.Run unwaited to start background running tasks which I think it equivilant to the OP's thread.start

Comment: protected async void DoStuff() ? or protected async Task DoStuff()?  Any async void should be avoided unless it's an event being triggered. Task.Run is the same as TaskFactory.StartNew, then Task.Wait, which is the same as new Thread(), then Thread.Wait(0); (from my memory here). If DoStuff doesn't have any tasks within it, we have to create a task in order to await it. Simply adding async to a method doesn't make it an async call. This is one of the problems with async void. It's a false async method. We need to get it into a Task. Once we have the Task, we can wait it. Task.Run is shorthand.

Comment: sorry typo. my question boils down to : "is 'await Task.Run(lambdaFunction)' differnt from 'await asyncFunctionCall()'

Comment: No different. Just gives you a way to do work inline. This is useful if you don't even want your work as a private method because you don't want it called any other way than right there. If I ever want the same code used elsewhere, I would put it in a private async method first, then promote to a protected if needed, then finally public if needed. Sorry for rambling in my other comments :)